# How to insert string start with `'` to postgresql when `psql` in bash？

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
res_dir='/home/me'
db_port='5432'
db_name='test'
db_user='postgres'
db_password='passwoed'
table_name='record'

#input something start with \ will get error
read -p 'input site:    ' site_input

res="'string";
psql postgresql://"$db_user":"$db_password"@localhost:"$db_port"/"$db_name" << EOF
INSERT INTO "$table_name" (site,res) VALUES ($site_input,$res);
EOF
```

Above script will get error when your input string start with `'`.

```
input site:    'jh
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "string"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "record" (site,res) VALUES ('jh,'string);
                                                     ^
```

I also tried other methods as below,but none workable.

```
psql postgresql://"$db_user":"$db_password"@localhost:"$db_port"/"$db_name" << EOF
INSERT INTO "$table_name" (site,res) VALUES ('|| $site_input || ','|| $res || ');
EOF


psql postgresql://"$db_user":"$db_password"@localhost:"$db_port"/"$db_name" << EOF
INSERT INTO "$table_name" (site,res) VALUES (quote_literal($site_input),quote_literal($res));
EOF
```

How to insert string start with `'` to postgresql when `psql` in bash？

Comment: *Don't* construct queries by interpolation or concatenation in the first place. Use parameters instead. No amount of escaping can prevent SQL injections or conversion errors.

Comment: The advice from @PanagiotisKanavos is sound -- escaping SQL is surprisingly difficult, and keeping data entirely out-of-band from query text is the only sure way to prevent leaks. Unfortunately, this often means that bash is the wrong tool for the job -- in a past life, I wrote a SQL client in Python _specifically_ to make it easy to safely run database queries with arbitrary parameter data from bash. (Alas, this was property of a startup that's now long since out-of-business, and I didn't think to include it when asking them to open-source some of the code I'd written during my time there).

Comment: If you want to import data stored in a file, why not use COPY? It's a lot easier and faster (and safer) than trying to construct INSERT statements from each input row

Comment: for examples of copy from stdin, try running pg_dump on your table 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape single quotes by doubling them :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
res_dir='/home/me'
db_port='5432'
db_name='test'
db_user='postgres'
db_password='passwoed'
table_name='record'

#input something start with \ will get error
read -p 'input site:    ' site_input

res="'string";

######## Doubling single quotes
site_input="${site_input//\'/\'\'}"
res="${res//\'/\'\'}"

######## Updated with '$site_input','$res'
psql postgresql://"$db_user":"$db_password"@localhost:"$db_port"/"$db_name" << EOF
INSERT INTO "$table_name" (site,res) VALUES ('$site_input','$res');
EOF
```

`//\'/\'\'` replaces all single quote `'` by `''`

For more information, see [Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Could you pls explain `//\'/\'\'` of  `res="${res//\'/\'\'}"`?